# PowerShell: executing a command on all WSL2 VMs

Tags: powershell, for-loop, wsl-2

I don't think the question needs a lot of clarification, especially when you see what I tried:

```
wsl -l -q --running | Where{$_ -ne ""} | ForEach {Write-Output "Distro $_"; wsl -d $_ -e ls; Write-Output "/// $_"}
```

I wanted/expected the above to write "`Distro (distribution name)`" on the console, then execute `ls` on that distribution, and then write "`/// (distribution name)`" on the console at the end, for each active VM. The part that doesn't work is the `ls` – **instead of executing `ls`, I get the generic help message from `wsl`**.

I think I'm not escaping something properly, because if I try to deliberately mangle the command by removing the distro name parameter (i.e. `wsl -d -e ls` instead of `wsl -d $_ -e ls`) I get a sensible error message (`There is no distribution with the supplied name.`) instead of the generic help message.

On the other hand, if I just run `wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e ls` manually in a console, that behaves as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was caused by `wsl`. Amazingly, it spits out the distro names in a bizarre encoding, which it then refuses when that gets fed back to it. Check it out:

```
wsl -l | Format-Hex
```

My solution (at least for the time being) is to just remove null characters from `wsl`'s output:

```
(wsl -l) -replace "`0", "" | Format-Hex
```

looks much better.

We just have to use this trick in our original script:

```
(wsl -l -q --running) -replace "`0", "" | Where{$_ -ne ""} | ForEach {Write-Output "Distro $_"; wsl -d $_ -e ls; Write-Output "/// $_"}
```